# Data Project For Android

Tags: android, database, save, cloud

I want to make an Android app that will save data in a table or in any other format from the entries made in the textboxes. I also want to upload the data to the cloud on day to day basis. i.e I want to upload all the data entered today to a cloud like Dropbox at the end of the day in a single file.

I want to ask If you have any similar projects that you can share with me? I want to learn how to save data on the mobile as well as save it to the cloud.

Please help as I am unable to proceed further in my quest for Android knowledge.

Comment: Please search on `Google` for that...and never ask such a questions over here in SO.

Comment: I searched google for the last 3 days but didnot find any project related to the above desription. Please help

Comment: You'll have to find cloud services, and see what API's they offer to upload data from the mobile devices. How the data is stored on the mobile devices is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways to store data in Android. If you want to work with cloud-based services I would recommend start by reading about **SQLite** and **Google Cloud Messaging**.